# Error message with virtuabox with ubuntu as host

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I installed virtuabox from their site and now I get this error message when trying to run `VBox`

```
 The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module          
available for the current kernel (3.16.0-36-generic) or it failed to          
load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by
             sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup           
You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed. Unknown 
application - VBox
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have  to recompile the kernel module and install it by

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

If some error appears then try this solution:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose
```

This will take care of dependencies like the kernel headers which is included in the package linux-headers-generic

But if you've a PAE kernel, you need to install the headers first:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Answer (score 1):

Virtualbox needs to load a module to the host's kernel. It seems you're missing that `vboxdrv` module, or it can't be loaded for some reason. Normally the `vboxdrv` is compiled and installed while installing Virtualbox.

If you just installed Virtualbox and didn't reboot your machine since then, it might be enough to reboot. Because the kernel modules are typically loaded at boot time. [In principle, you can load and unload modules on a running system as well, but in this case I'd reckon a reboot might be the simpler solution.]

If that does not work, you might need to re-install Virtualbox and take note of any error messages that might appear. Maybe, for some reason, the `vboxdrv` module can't be compiled or installed.

Also, be aware that kernel modules are specific to a kernel. If you installed a different kernel since installing Virtualbox, that new kernel does not necessarily have the `vboxdrv` module that was installed to the "original" kernel that was running when Virtualbox was installed.